# Having a better complexity / adversary argument for finding if a finite automata accepts a palindrome

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, finite-automata, adversary

> Let $A$ be a DFA over a finite alphabet $ \Sigma$. Find an algorithm that indicates if $A$ accepts a palindrome and give the complexity of this algorithm.

Here is my solution:

If we denote $^t A$ the transpose of the finite automaton then in order to see if $A$ accepts a palindrome we need to look at the product automaton of $A$ and $^t A$ and find if this product automaton accepts a word. If yes then this is word is a palindrome.

Finding the transpose of a finite automaton takes $O(|V|)$ where $V$ is the number of transition of our finite automaton. Take the product of $A$ and its transpose takes $O(|V|^2)$. And looking if an automaton accept a word takes $O(|V|^{|S|})$, where $|S|$ is the number of states of our finite automaton. So the final complexity I get for the algorithm I described above is: 
$$O(|V|^{3 + 2|S|})$$

Now my question is:

Is it possible to improve the complexity? And is it possible to give a proof (using I guess adversary argument) to prove that there isn't a better algorithm (in the sense of complexity) to find if a finite automaton accepts a palindrome?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this in $O(n^2)$, where $n$ is the number of states in the original DFA (or NFA), using your idea. Compute the product automaton of the original automaton and its reverse. The new automaton contains $O(n^2)$ states. As to the number of edges, in the original DFA, each state has $|\Sigma|$ outgoing edges, and in its reverse, there are $|\Sigma|n$ transitions overall. Let us denote by $a(q)$ the number of outgoing transitions from $q$ in the original DFA, and by $b(q)$ the number in the reverse DFA. Using $Q$ for the set of states, the total number of transitions in the product automaton is
$$
\sum_{q_1,q_2 \in Q} a(q_1) b(q_2) =
\sum_{q_1,q_2 \in Q} |\Sigma| b(q_2) =
|\Sigma| n \sum_{q_2 \in Q} b(q_2) =
|\Sigma|^2 n^2.
$$
Assuming $|\Sigma|$ is constant, this is $O(n^2)$.
Now check whether some final state is reachable from some initial state, using BFS/DFS, in  time $O(n^2)$.

We can prove an essentially matching lower bound given SETH. Recall that SETH states that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $k$ such that $k$-SAT cannot be solved in time $O(2^{(1-\epsilon) n})$, where $n$ is the number of variables. We will show how to reduce $k$-SAT to your problem.

Given a $k$-SAT formula $\phi$ with $n$ variables and $m = O(n^k)$ clauses, consider the following language $L$ of all words of the form $\alpha x \beta \gamma y \delta$, where:

1. $|\alpha| = |\beta| = |\gamma| = |\delta| = n/2$, $|x| = |y| = m$.
2. We think of $\alpha$ as an assignment for the first $n/2$ variables. If $x_i = 0$ then $\alpha$ must satisfy the $i$th clause.
3. We think of $\beta$ as an assignment for the last $n/2$ variables. If $y^R_i = y_{m+1-i} = 1$ then $\beta$ must satisfy the $i$th clause.

Any word in $L \cap L^R$ must be of the form $\alpha x \beta \beta^R x^R \alpha^R$, and so by construction $\alpha\beta$ satisfies $\phi$. Conversely, if $\alpha\beta$ satisfies $\phi$, then we can choose $x$ so that the corresponding word is in $L \cap L^R$, Hence $\phi$ is satisfiable iff $L \cap L^R$ is non-empty.

How many states do we need to accept $L$? We can read and store $\alpha$ using $O(2^{n/2})$ many states. Therefore using $O(2^{n/2} m)$ states, we can verify the second condition (on $\alpha x$). Similarly, we can verify the third condition (on $\beta y$) using $O(2^{n/2} m)$ more states. Verifying the first condition takes $O(n+m)$ more states, for a grand total of $O(2^{n/2} m) = O(2^{n/2 + o(1)})$ states.

If your problem could be solve in time $O(N^{2-\delta})$ (where $N$ is the number of states in the input automaton), then we would get an algorithm for $k$-SAT running in time $O(2^{(1-\delta/2)n + o(1)})$, and so obtain a contradiction if $\delta/2 \geq \epsilon$. This shows that assuming SETH, your problem cannot be solved in $O(N^{2-\delta)}$ for any $\delta > 0$.

Comment: I don’t see any $O(1)$ in the answer.

Comment: Assuming the alphabet is fixed, the number of transitions only differs from the number of states by a constant factor.

Comment: If you have multiple initial states, add a new initial state with epsilon transitions to all of them.

Comment: I don't see why the number of transitions only differs from the number of states by a constant. I mean each state can have a transition to every other state in an NFA. And in this case the number of transitions is : $O(n^2)$... and not $O(n)$

Comment: This can't really happen since the NFA is not arbitrary – it's obtained from a DFA by reversing all arrows. See my updated answer.

Comment: Oh I see that's clever. Thank you for you for the explanation. So we can see if an automaton accepts a word in linear only if it's a DFA or if it's an NFA with $kn$ transition where $k$ is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem in polynomial time. For simplicity let's assume the DFA has a single accepting state. If it has multiple you can just run this algorithm for each accepting state until you return $\text{YES}$ or every accepting state has been unsuccessfully tried and we return $\text{NO}$. Let $\text{goto}(x, s) = y$ indicate that there is a transition from state $x$ to state $y$ on symbol $s$.

We use a meet in the middle strategy. We have a tuple $(b, e)$ where $b$ is the state reached from the beginning, and $e$ is the state reached from the end.

We build  a list of these tuples. Initially we have only one such tuple $(b, e) = (\text{init}, \text{accept})$. Then as long as our list has a tuple that hasn't been expanded before, we expand tuple $(b, e)$ by adding all $(b', e')$ to the list for each possible symbol $s$ where $\text{goto}(b, s) = b'$ and $\text{goto}(e', s) = e$.

We return $\text{YES}$ if we have added $(x, x)$ to the list, or $(x, y)$ where some $s$ exists such that $\text{goto}(x, s) = y$. The former case indicates an even length palindrome, the latter an odd length palindrome.

Why is this polynomial time? Hint: there are only $|S|^2$ possible tuples $(b, e)$ we ever need to expand.